# Understanding Python List Comprehension equivalent

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I have the following code:

```
listOfStrings = ['i_am_exercising', 'python_functional', 'lists_comprehension']
[ "".join([elem.title() for elem in splited]) for splited in [el.split("_")for el in listOfStrings]]
```

the result of this is:

```
['IAmExercising', 'PythonFunctional', 'ListsComprehension']
```

reading the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), i got the equivalent extended version, which puts the first expression in a variable to be appended and the second expression in a list to be iterated with the for statement:

```
returned = []
for splited in [el.split("_")for el in listOfStrings]: 
            returned.append("".join([elem.title() for elem in splited]))
```

but if i want **write the same code without any list comprehension, how is the best way to do this?** i tried with the following code, which works well:

```
returned = []
temp = []

for el in listOfStrings:                 
    temp = []                          
    for splited in el.split("_"):       
        temp.append(splited.title())  
    returned.append("".join(temp))
```

but i didn't completely understood how to do this (transform the list comprehension to an equivalent full extended form)

Comment: Pedantic point: `"".join(elem.title() for elem in splited)` is *technically* free of a list comprehension, since it passes a generator directly to `join`, instead of a list created by a list comprehension using the same generator. But such a distinction bypasses your real question :)

Comment: thanks for the point of generator =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily convert from outwards to inwards:

```
listOfStrings = ['i_am_exercising', 'python_functional', 'lists_comprehension']

result = [ "".join([elem.title() for elem in split]) for split in [el.split("_")for el in listOfStrings]]
print result

result = []
for split in [el.split("_") for el in listOfStrings]:
    result.append("".join([elem.title() for elem in split]))
print result

result = []
temp1 = []
for el in listOfStrings:
    temp1.append(el.split("_"))
for split in temp1:
    result.append("".join([elem.title() for elem in split]))
print result

result = []
temp1 = []
for el in listOfStrings:
    temp1.append(el.split("_"))
for split in temp1:
    temp2 = []
    for elem in split:
        temp2.append(elem.title())
    result.append("".join(temp2))
print result
```

Basically you just follow the following scheme:

```
result = [foo for bar in baz]
```

is turned into

```
result = []
for bar in baz:
    result.append(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have both a *nested* list comprehensions, one inside the other, plus another one to create a list of split elements first. You can reduce this to just two loops instead:

```
returned = []
for el in listOfStrings:
    tmp = []
    for splited in el.split("_"):
        tmp.append(splited.title())
    returned.append("".join(tmp))
```

This simplifies back down to a list comprehension of the form:

```
["".join([splited.title() for splited in el.split("_")]) for el in listOfStrings]
```