# Unroll Python chained list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have come across the following chained list comprehension code in the online book A Programmer's Guide to Data Mining (chapter 8) and it's a bit confusing.

First example:

```
self.centroids = [[self.data[i][r]  for i in range(1, len(self.data))]
                   for r in random.sample(range(len(self.data[0])), self.k)]
```

Second example:

```
self.centroids = [[sum([self.data[k][i] for i in range(len(self.data[0]))
                   if self.memberOf[i] == centroid])/members[centroid]
                   for k in range(1, len(self.data))]
                   for centroid in range(len(self.centroids))]
```

I want the equivalent regular for loop syntax (non-list comprehension) for this code. I tried to do with the help of [Understanding Python List Comprehension equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595296/understanding-python-list-comprehension-equivalent) but am going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.centroids = [[self.data[i][r]  for i in range(1, len(self.data))]
        for r in random.sample(range(len(self.data[0])), self.k)]
```

What this does is select k random points in the data to be centroids.

```
random.sample(range(len(self.data[0])), self.k)
```

returns a list of k unique random elements from the list 
`[0, 1, 2, .... len(self.data[0]) -1]`

so if we have 100 items in our data and k is 3, this will return a list of 3 random items from the list [0, 1, 2, ...99]

Let's call this something:

```
c = random.sample(range(len(self.data[0])), self.k)
```

Then we would have something like:

```
self.centroids = []
for r in c:
  tmp = []
  for i in range(1, len(self.data)):   # this is how many columns 
                                       #(attributes) each data instance has.
      tmp.append(self.data[i][r])
  self.centroids.append(tmp)
```

So, for example, suppose our data looked like:

```
self.data = 
 [['basketball', 'basketball', 'runner', 
   'gymnast', 'gymnast', 'basketball', 'runner']
  [70, 72, 67, 58, 57, 71, 70],
  [148, 165, 135, 87, 85, 143, 140]]
```

and our random sample c was [1, 3]
the above code would make

```
self.centroids = [[72, 165], [58, 87]]
```

The next one you mention:

```
self.centroids = [[sum([self.data[k][i] for i in range(len(self.data[0]))
               if self.memberOf[i] == centroid])/members[centroid]
               for k in range(1, len(self.data))]
               for centroid in range(len(self.centroids))]
```

This one is like:

```
tmpCentroids = []
for centroid in range(len(self.centroids)):  # so for each centroid 
   tmpCentroid = []
   for k in range(1, len(self.data)):        # and for each column (attribute) in the data
     total = 0
     for i in range (len(self.data[0])):     # for each data instance 
       if self.memberOf[i] == centroid       # if that instance is a member of that centroid group
          total += self.data[k][i]           # add that instances column value to the column total
     tmpCentroid.append(total/members[centroid])  # compute the avg. column value for that group
   tmpCentroids.append(tmpCentroid)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. Just as one last step, we would have to assign self.centroids to tmpCentroids. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the first example is equivalent to

```
self.centroids=[]
for r in random.sample(range(len(self.data[0])),self.k):
    list_inner=[]
    for i in range(1, len(self.data)):
        list_inner.append(self.data[i][r])
    self.centroids.append(list_inner)
```

You can expand the second one in the same way.

edit: Again, no way to test this really, but the second one should be:

```
self.centroids = []
for centroid in range(len(self.centroids)):
    middle = []
    for k in range(1, len(self.data)):
        inner = []
        for i in range(len(self.data[0])):
            if self.memberOf[i] == centroid:
                inner.append(self.data[k][i])
        middle.append(sum(inner)/members[centroid])
    self.centroids.append(middle)
```

Comment: The outer to inner unroll works for a single list with multiple for loops. Is it not the same for a list within a list? Specfically, the for-loop (with the random.sample call) should be the outer loop or the inner loop?

The second example is the more complicated one, I am going very wrong on that.

Comment: Your code looks mostly ok, but it's missing a couple of `)`s.

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now.

Comment: I still need help with the second example, I am more of a Java / Ruby programmer. The call to sum and division by members[centroid] is where I am going wrong.
`    self.centroids = []
    for centroid in range(len(self.centroids)):
        list_first_inner=[]
        for k in range(1, len(self.data)):
            list_second_inner=[]
            for i in range(len(self.data[0])):
                if self.memberOf[i] == centroid:`

After this, what should happen? I tried various things, but am getting errors.

Comment: `self.centroids = []
    for centroid in range(len(self.centroids)):
        list_first_inner=[]
        for k in range(1, len(self.data)):
            list_second_inner=[]
            for i in range(len(self.data[0])):
                if self.memberOf[i] == centroid:`

Comment: @L3viathan Where does sum go?

Comment: @user1575148 Whoops, dropped it while moving code around. Fixed, see edit.

Comment: @L3viathan For some reason, I am getting 
    IndexError: list index out of range
My testing is simple. The code and the data files are in http://guidetodatamining.com/chapter-8/
    Code file = kmeans.py and data file = dogs.csv
I am replacing the original loop in updateCentroids method with your loop and running the program.

Comment: I don't really want to go through the book to find the mistake, in which line do you have the error? Does it not occur when using the original version?